# wxpython GetStatusText()

Tags: python, wxpython

Hey, I have a wxpython frame object with a status bar. I can do self.SetStatusText() without any trouble, but when I do self.GetStatusText() I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File
 "D:\python\code\test.pyw",
 line 87, in <module>
     frame = mainframe()   File "D:\python\code\test.pyw",
 line 40, in __init__
     self.serverfield.SetValue(self.serverinfo())
 File
 "D:\python\code\test.pyw",
 line 78, in serverinfo
     status = self.GetStatusText(0) AttributeError: 'mainframe' object has
 no attribute 'GetStatusText'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no such function. See [the documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html). Try `self.GetStatusBar().GetStatusText()`, as defined [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StatusBar-class.html).